Tool for testing bouncing keys on a keyboard
I bought a Logitech G910 and it seems that it suffers from bouncing keys, as reported by many people. Now I want to figure out which keys are affected, so that I can a) either return the defective product and give detailed feedback on which keys are affected or b) repair those keys by replacing the switches.
Which tool can help me identify bouncing keys and list them?
The tool needs to be gratis and work on Windows 10.
I don't need a software that tries to fix the bouncing keys on the PC side. My goal is to have a working hardware.
I have tried:

keybounce-detect, which is for Linux

